# Puppet master can't accept a request

Tags: linux, puppet

This is what I am getting when connecting to puppetmaster using `puppetd --test`. I have an entry for puppetmaster in my client's `/etc/hosts`:

```
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

I don't know why it's happening. There's no `autosign.conf` in my puppetmaster. There are no pending certificates to sign. In fact, there's no certificate request already present.

Answer (score 2):

When you run:

`puppet cert list --all`

-from the master

Do you see the certificate for the agent machine listed?

Is the master defined correctly in your `puppet.conf` file?

Are you running Puppet Open Source or Puppet Enterprise?

Depending on the answer to that your directory locations will be different:
Enterprise: `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet`
Open Source: `/etc/puppet`

Once you get to the puppet directory where your manifests and modules directories are go into the `ssl` directory `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl`

You should see several directories:

Look in the `certs` directory. If you server is named `server1` you should have a `server1.dnsname.com.pem` certificate file.

Look at it via `cat server1.dnsname.com.pem`

It should match the certificate in the same location on the agent (match mean be identical).
Also, on the master you should have the same cert located in the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/signed`

If any of them are off or if you want to re-authorize an agents certificates from the master run a `puppet cert clean server1.dnsname.com` and it will revoke and remove all instances of the agents certificate from the master and you can re-request and re-sign a new one from the agent. Additionally, I would run a search after the clean to make sure that it got them all and delete any stragglers.

Let me know if any of this helps or simply cause you more frustration.

Before you run any command like: `puppet cert clean` etc... you can get more information with the options by adding `--help` as in - `puppet cert --help`

Comment: LinuxlyChallenged, I am using the open source version. I see some entries using puppet cert list --all, but i am not able to see the required client's request. Actually, i get the above mentioned warnings and errors everytime when i do a puppet run from that client. I have done puppet cert clean --all and tried again many times, but the error persists.